# Obtener un documento xhr cuando se visita una página

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, scraping

Intenté obtener los elementos que podemos ver abajo de las fotos sobre [el siguiente sitio](https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no puedo obtenerlo desde el codigo fuente. Suponía que se descaraba dinamicamente con un script javascript. En efecto parece ser en un documento xhr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces ¿Cómo puedo obtener un documento xhr que se descarga al visitar una página?

Intenté:

```
url = "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html"

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e72156ddb336> in <module>()
      2 
      3 r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
----> 4 data = r.json()
      5 
      6 print(data)

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Te falta añadir que contiene `headers` y el import de la librería `requests` ! :)

Answer (score 0):

La función `requests.post()` devuelve un objeto `requests.models.Response` que tiene varios atributos importantes, vamos a ver que sucede

Partiendo de tu código en el que dicho objeto request es `r` podemos hacer lo siguiente:

1. Ejecutar `r.ok` con esto veremos si la petición a la web, ha salido correcta o no, y cuando hacemos esto, el comando nos devuelve `False`. Es decir la petición que has realizado a la web no se ha ejecutado correctamente.
2. Seguimos indagando y ejecutamos el siguiente método `r.raise_for_status()`. Este método nos devuelve el estado concreto de nuestra petición: `HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html`

El `error 403`, significa petición denegada, resumiendo, lo que ha pasado es que la página web que estás intentando scrapear *te ha cazado*, sabe que no eres un ser humano, y por tanto te está impidiendo acceder a su sitio web.

Por ello cuando intentas  utilizar el método `r.json()` te da el error que tu has mendicionado `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. Porque al intentar decodificar la página en un json, se encuentra que no hay nada, porque **no ha podido scrapearla.**

### Solución

No hay una solución concreta, cada página es un mundo, pero deberías incluir en los `headers` los siguientes cambios

- Usar un servidor proxy
- Usar un User Agent. Esto es lo que te identifica como usuario, el que trae request por defecto basicamente le dice a la página que es un robot, por lo que si no lo cambias seguramente no te permitan entrar.
- Rotar el servidor proxy, User Agent y Referrer, es decir cambiarlos.
- Crear intervalos de tiempo amplios entre tus peticiones, es decir, que no haga 100 peticiones a una página web por segundo.

Basicamente estas estrategías lo que tratan es de conseguir que la página web piense que eres un usuario real, que está navengado por el sitio.